# The introduction link in the on-topic FAQ is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed

If you visit https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, you will see the following encouragement:

> *New users* (even users familiar with the Stack Exchange format) *should read our [introduction to the site](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) before posting.*

However (as reproduced above), the link points to `meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com` rather than `skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com`. The result is an SSL error:

[image: An error message that reports: This site can't provide a secure connection]

Speaking as a "new user" who is familiar with the Stack Exchange format, I naturally visited the on-topic page to find just this kind of information. The bad link is a barrier for new users and should be fixed ASAP.

Comment: These were recently marked (status-completed), too: 
[TLS for meta.*.stackexchange.com, again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372657), 
[HTTPS certificate error for meta redirect pages (meta.<site>.stackexchange.com)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299086) and 
[meta.*.stackexchange.com redirection does not work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393351).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fixed, thanks! (the "researching the evidence " link is now also pointing to the correct domain)